# Inanimate pronouns in Hindi

Tags: pronouns, animacy, hindustani

Could someone give me some examples of inanimate pronouns in Hindi? I can't come up with any example myself. I was reading this paper:

[*Gazetteer Method for Resolving Pronominal Anaphora in Hindi Language*](http://www.warse.org/pdfs/2014/ijacst04332014.pdf)

where the authors said that they made a list of inanimate pronouns (they call them *non animistic*). But I can't find any such pronoun. According to me, every pronoun in Hindi could also be used for animate objects.

Comment: "Animistic" is a term from anthropology, not linguistics. Linguists call this distinction "animate"/"inanimate". But they give example(s?) and I assume you can read Devanagari? Is their example wrong?

Comment: Yes i can read devanagari but they haven't given any examples for inanimate pronouns. Only examples of animate pronouns has been provided there.

Answer (score 4):

> [कुछ](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.0:6631.mcgregor) (*kuch*) "something"
>
> [क्या](https://dsalsrv04.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/mcgregor_query.py?qs=%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE&searchhws=yes) (*kyā*) "what?"

are examples of inanimate pronouns<sup>1</sup> in Hindi (as opposed to the animate [कोई](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.0:7095.mcgregor) (*koī*) "someone; anyone" and [कौन](https://dsalsrv04.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/mcgregor_query.py?qs=%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8C%E0%A4%A8&searchhws=yes) (*kaun*) "who?").

---

<sup>1. Specifically, the inanimate singular [indefinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_pronoun) and interrogative pronouns.</sup>

<sup>**Source:** [*Hindi*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ooH5VfLTQEQC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62), Yamuna Kachru (p.62)</sup>

Comment: But you can say "कुछ लोग" *some people*. I don't think कुछ is a pronoun but rather a determiner.

Comment: And I'm not 100% sure about this but you can also say "कोई खाना है" *is there any food?* so I don't think your answer is correct.

Comment: @Aryaman कोई can be a pronoun or an adjective, context depending. कुछ can similarly be either a pronoun, adjective, or adverb. Specifically they're *indefinite pronouns*. See here: ["कोई"](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.0:7095.mcgregor) and here: ["कुछ " - The Oxford English-Hindi Dictionary](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.0:6631.mcgregor)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I don't think Hindi has a true animate/non-animate distinction nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

In Hindi, he/she/it are a single pronoun, i.e. there is no distinction between inanimate and animate. The only distinction in pronouns is distance (near and far) and number (singular and plural).

The pronouns are:

- यह - he/she/it (near)
- वह - he/she/it (far)
- ये - they (near)
- वे - they (far)